# Hangman game project - new feature to enable user to select from few different categories of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I wrote a simple hangman game in which users can guess 20 different fruits.

```
import tkinter as tk

# define the list of words to be guessed
words = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango', 'pineapple', 'watermelon', 'grapes', 'kiwi', 'peach', 'pear', 'plum', 'cherry', 'blueberry', 'raspberry', 'strawberry', 'papaya', 'cantaloupe', 'grapefruit', 'pomegranate', 'fig',]

# define the initial number of lives and the initial state of the game
lives = 6
word = ""
guesses = []

# define the GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Hangman Game')

# define the canvas for the drawing
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

# define the function to draw the gallows
def draw_gallows():
    canvas.create_line(50, 350, 350, 350)
    canvas.create_line(200, 350, 200, 50)
    canvas.create_line(200, 50, 300, 50)
    canvas.create_line(300, 50, 300, 100)

# define the function to update the drawing based on the number of lives left
def update_drawing():
    canvas.delete('all')
    draw_gallows()
    if lives < 6:
        canvas.create_oval(280, 100, 320, 140)
    if lives < 5:
        canvas.create_line(300, 140, 300, 220)
    if lives < 4:
        canvas.create_line(300, 160, 280, 200)
    if lives < 3:
        canvas.create_line(300, 160, 320, 200)
    if lives < 2:
        canvas.create_line(300, 220, 280, 280)
    if lives < 1:
        canvas.create_line(300, 220, 320, 280)

# define the function to start a new game
def new_game():
    global lives, word, guesses
    lives = 6
    word = words.pop()
    guesses = []
    update_drawing()
    display_word()

# define the function to handle a guess
def handle_guess(event):
    global lives, word, guesses
    if lives > 0 and word:
        letter = entry.get()
        if len(letter) == 1 and letter.isalpha() and letter not in guesses:
            guesses.append(letter)
            if letter not in word:
                lives -= 1
            update_drawing()
            if set(word).issubset(set(guesses)):
                label.config(text=f"You win! The word was '{word}'.")
                word = ""
            elif lives == 0:
                label.config(text=f"You lose! The word was '{word}'.")
                word = ""
            else:
                entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                label.config(text=f"Lives: {lives}, Guesses: {' '.join(guesses)}")
                display_word()
        else:
            entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            if len(letter) != 1:
                label.config(text="Error: Please enter a single letter.")
            elif not letter.isalpha():
                label.config(text="Error: Please enter a letter.")
            elif letter in guesses:
                label.config(text="Error: You already guessed that letter.") 


# define the input field and the label to display the game status
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry.bind('<Return>', handle_guess)

label = tk.Label(root, text=f"Lives: {lives}, Guesses: {' '.join(guesses)}")
label.grid(row=1, column=1)

# define the button to start a new game
button = tk.Button(root, text="New Game", command=new_game)
button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

# define the function to display the word as underscores
def display_word():
    display = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter in guesses:
            display += letter + " "
        else:
            display += "_ "
    label.config(text=display)
    
# start the GUI main loop
new_game()
root.mainloop()
```

However, I wanted to implement a feature that:

1. enables users to select different categories of words in form of a simple main menu prior to starting the game

```
# define the list of words for each category
categories = {
    'Animals': ['lion', 'elephant', 'giraffe', 'zebra', 'rhinoceros', 'monkey', 'tiger', 'panda', 'cheetah', 'hippopotamus', 'leopard', 'gazelle', 'crocodile', 'kangaroo', 'koala', 'ostrich', 'wolf', 'lynx', 'hedgehog', 'penguin'],
    'Countries': ['Australia', 'Canada', 'Brazil', 'Mexico', 'Japan', 'India', 'France', 'Russia', 'Egypt', 'Nigeria', 'Italy', 'China', 'Spain', 'Kenya', 'Argentina', 'South Africa', 'Germany', 'Switzerland', 'New Zealand', 'Thailand'],
    'Sports': ['football', 'basketball', 'baseball', 'tennis', 'soccer', 'golf', 'hockey', 'swimming', 'cycling', 'boxing', 'volleyball', 'cricket', 'skiing', 'figure skating', 'surfing', 'karate', 'wrestling', 'gymnastics', 'rowing', 'badminton'],
    'Movies': ['The Godfather', 'Forrest Gump', 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'Pulp Fiction', 'The Lord of the Rings', 'Star Wars', 'The Dark Knight', 'The Matrix', 'The Silence of the Lambs', 'The Green Mile', 'Gladiator', 'Goodfellas', 'Jurassic Park', 'Back to the Future', 'Terminator', 'Titanic', 'Fight Club', 'Indiana Jones', 'The Lion King', 'Ghostbusters'],
    'Famous People': ['Muhammad Ali', 'Albert Einstein', 'Marilyn Monroe', 'Oprah Winfrey', 'Elon Musk', 'Barack Obama', 'Nelson Mandela', 'Martin Luther King Jr.', 'Steve Jobs', 'Mother Teresa', 'Walt Disney', 'Malala Yousafzai', 'Pablo Picasso', 'Leonardo da Vinci', 'Beethoven', 'Vincent van Gogh', 'Stephen Hawking', 'Marie Curie', 'Jane Austen', 'William Shakespeare'],
    'Colors': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'purple', 'pink', 'black', 'white', 'brown', 'gray', 'magenta', 'turquoise', 'gold', 'silver', 'beige', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive', 'teal'],
    'Professions': ['architect', 'photographer', 'teacher', 'doctor', 'chef', 'engineer', 'writer', 'artist', 'musician', 'actor', 'lawyer', 'pilot', 'nurse', 'scientist', 'athlete', 'entrepreneur', 'designer', 'journalist', 'psychologist', 'veterinarian']
}
```

2. a button next to "New Game" button that returns user to this category selection menu

Would someone be able to assist?

No idea how to do something like that yet.

EDIT: I managed to do that and add 2 new buttons however can't space them evenly with padding

```
# define the button to start a new game
button = tk.Button(root, text="New Game", command=new_game, width=10)
button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

# define the button to return to the category selection menu
menu_button = tk.Button(root, text="Return to Menu", command=return_to_menu, width=10)
menu_button.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

# define the button to add a new word
add_button = tk.Button(root, text="Add Word", command=add_word, width=10)
add_button.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFgLe.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put those buttons in a frame:

```py
...
# frame for the buttons
bottom = tk.Frame(root)
bottom.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

# define the button to start a new game
button = tk.Button(bottom, text="New Game", command=new_game, width=20)
button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

# define the button to return to the category selection menu
menu_button = tk.Button(bottom, text="Return to Menu", command=return_to_menu, width=20)
menu_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

# define the button to add a new word
add_button = tk.Button(bottom, text="Add Word", command=add_word, width=20)
add_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
...
```

Result:

[image]